# Gdal 2.1.3 Rasterize "kml not recognized as a supported file format"

Tags: gdal, kml, rasterization

I am really new to gdal and have a real simple kml file. I tested this kml file in google earth and there was no problem displaying it. But when I try to rasterize it I get the following error: 

 "text.kml not recognized as a supported file format". 

 My command is:

```
gdal_rasterize -of "Gtiff" -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -burn 127 -init 0 -init 0 -init 0 -init 0 -ot Byte -ts 800 800 test.kml test.tiff
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

*Update:*

 Using gets me:
`gdal_info --formats
 VRT -raster- (rw+v): Virtual Raster
  GTiff -raster- (rw+vs): GeoTIFF
  NITF -raster- (rw+vs): National Imagery Transmission Format
  RPFTOC -raster- (rovs): Raster Product Format TOC format
  ECRGTOC -raster- (rovs): ECRG TOC format
  HFA -raster- (rw+v): Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
  SAR_CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS SAR Image
  CEOS -raster- (rov): CEOS Image
  JAXAPALSAR -raster- (rov): JAXA PALSAR Product Reader (Level 1.1/1.5)
  GFF -raster- (rov): Ground-based SAR Applications Testbed File Format (.gff)
  ELAS -raster- (rw+v): ELAS
  AIG -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Binary Grid
  AAIGrid -raster- (rwv): Arc/Info ASCII Grid
  GRASSASCIIGrid -raster- (rov): GRASS ASCII Grid
  SDTS -raster- (rov): SDTS Raster
  DTED -raster- (rwv): DTED Elevation Raster
  PNG -raster- (rwv): Portable Network Graphics
  JPEG -raster- (rwv): JPEG JFIF
  MEM -raster- (rw+): In Memory Raster
  JDEM -raster- (rov): Japanese DEM (.mem)
  GIF -raster- (rwv): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
  BIGGIF -raster- (rov): Graphics Interchange Format (.gif)
  ESAT -raster- (rov): Envisat Image Format
  BSB -raster- (rov): Maptech BSB Nautical Charts
  XPM -raster- (rwv): X11 PixMap Format
  BMP -raster- (rw+v): MS Windows Device Independent Bitmap
  DIMAP -raster- (rov): SPOT DIMAP
  AirSAR -raster- (rov): AirSAR Polarimetric Image
  RS2 -raster- (ros): RadarSat 2 XML Product
  SAFE -raster- (rov): Sentinel-1 SAR SAFE Product
  PCIDSK -raster,vector- (rw+v): PCIDSK Database File
  PCRaster -raster- (rw+): PCRaster Raster File
  ILWIS -raster- (rw+v): ILWIS Raster Map
  SGI -raster- (rw+): SGI Image File Format 1.0
  SRTMHGT -raster- (rwv): SRTMHGT File Format
  Leveller -raster- (rw+): Leveller heightfield
  Terragen -raster- (rw+): Terragen heightfield
  ISIS3 -raster- (rov): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 3)
  ISIS2 -raster- (rw+v): USGS Astrogeology ISIS cube (Version 2)
  PDS -raster- (rov): NASA Planetary Data System
  VICAR -raster- (rov): MIPL VICAR file
  TIL -raster- (rov): EarthWatch .TIL
  ERS -raster- (rw+v): ERMapper .ers Labelled
  L1B -raster- (rovs): NOAA Polar Orbiter Level 1b Data Set
  FIT -raster- (rwv): FIT Image
  GRIB -raster- (rov): GRIdded Binary (.grb)
  RMF -raster- (rw+v): Raster Matrix Format
  WCS -raster- (rovs): OGC Web Coverage Service
  WMS -raster- (rwvs): OGC Web Map Service
  MSGN -raster- (ro): EUMETSAT Archive native (.nat)
  RST -raster- (rw+v): Idrisi Raster A.1
  INGR -raster- (rw+v): Intergraph Raster
  GSAG -raster- (rwv): Golden Software ASCII Grid (.grd)
  GSBG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software Binary Grid (.grd)
  GS7BG -raster- (rw+v): Golden Software 7 Binary Grid (.grd)
  COSAR -raster- (rov): COSAR Annotated Binary Matrix (TerraSAR-X)
  TSX -raster- (rov): TerraSAR-X Product
  COASP -raster- (ro): DRDC COASP SAR Processor Raster
  R -raster- (rwv): R Object Data Store
  MAP -raster- (rov): OziExplorer .MAP
  KMLSUPEROVERLAY -raster- (rwv): Kml Super Overlay
  PDF -raster,vector- (w+): Geospatial PDF
  Rasterlite -raster- (rws): Rasterlite
  MBTiles -raster- (rw+v): MBTiles
  PLMOSAIC -raster- (ro): Planet Labs Mosaics API
  CALS -raster- (rw): CALS (Type 1)
  WMTS -raster- (rwv): OGC Web Mab Tile Service
  SENTINEL2 -raster- (rovs): Sentinel 2
  MRF -raster- (rw+v): Meta Raster Format
  PNM -raster- (rw+v): Portable Pixmap Format (netpbm)
  DOQ1 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (Old Style)
  DOQ2 -raster- (rov): USGS DOQ (New Style)
  GenBin -raster- (rov): Generic Binary (.hdr Labelled)
  PAux -raster- (rw+): PCI .aux Labelled
  MFF -raster- (rw+v): Vexcel MFF Raster
  MFF2 -raster- (rw+): Vexcel MFF2 (HKV) Raster
  FujiBAS -raster- (ro): Fuji BAS Scanner Image
  GSC -raster- (rov): GSC Geogrid
  FAST -raster- (rov): EOSAT FAST Format
  BT -raster- (rw+v): VTP .bt (Binary Terrain) 1.3 Format
  LAN -raster- (rw+v): Erdas .LAN/.GIS
  CPG -raster- (ro): Convair PolGASP
  IDA -raster- (rw+v): Image Data and Analysis
  NDF -raster- (rov): NLAPS Data Format
  EIR -raster- (rov): Erdas Imagine Raw
  DIPEx -raster- (rov): DIPEx
  LCP -raster- (rwv): FARSITE v.4 Landscape File (.lcp)
  GTX -raster- (rw+v): NOAA Vertical Datum .GTX
  LOSLAS -raster- (rov): NADCON .los/.las Datum Grid Shift
  NTv2 -raster- (rw+vs): NTv2 Datum Grid Shift
  CTable2 -raster- (rw+v): CTable2 Datum Grid Shift
  ACE2 -raster- (rov): ACE2
  SNODAS -raster- (rov): Snow Data Assimilation System
  KRO -raster- (rw+v): KOLOR Raw
  ROI_PAC -raster- (rw+v): ROI_PAC raster
  ENVI -raster- (rw+v): ENVI .hdr Labelled
  EHdr -raster- (rw+v): ESRI .hdr Labelled
  ISCE -raster- (rw+v): ISCE raster
  ARG -raster- (rwv): Azavea Raster Grid format
  RIK -raster- (rov): Swedish Grid RIK (.rik)
  USGSDEM -raster- (rwv): USGS Optional ASCII DEM (and CDED)
  GXF -raster- (ro): GeoSoft Grid Exchange Format
  NWT_GRD -raster- (rov): Northwood Numeric Grid Format .grd/.tab
  NWT_GRC -raster- (rov): Northwood Classified Grid Format .grc/.tab
  ADRG -raster- (rw+vs): ARC Digitized Raster Graphics
  SRP -raster- (rovs): Standard Raster Product (ASRP/USRP)
  BLX -raster- (rwv): Magellan topo (.blx)
  PostGISRaster -raster- (rws): PostGIS Raster driver
  SAGA -raster- (rw+v): SAGA GIS Binary Grid (.sdat)
  XYZ -raster- (rwv): ASCII Gridded XYZ
  HF2 -raster- (rwv): HF2/HFZ heightfield raster
  OZI -raster- (rov): OziExplorer Image File
  CTG -raster- (rov): USGS LULC Composite Theme Grid
  E00GRID -raster- (rov): Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
  ZMap -raster- (rwv): ZMap Plus Grid
  NGSGEOID -raster- (rov): NOAA NGS Geoid Height Grids
  IRIS -raster- (rov): IRIS data (.PPI, .CAPPi etc)
  GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
  PLSCENES -raster,vector- (ro): Planet Labs Scenes API
  HTTP -raster,vector- (ro): HTTP Fetching Wrapper`

So only KML overlay is found. How do configure gdal so that a "normal" KML is read?

*Update2*
using ogrinfo test.kml says:
`FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource test.kml with the following drivers.
  -> PCIDSK
  -> PDF
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> OGR_SDTS
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> OGR_VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> OGR_GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> WAsP
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDUMP
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> OGR_PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Cloudant
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> Carto
  -> AmigoCloud
  -> SXF
  -> Selafin
  -> JML
  -> PLSCENES
  -> CSW
  -> VDV
  -> TIGER
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> HTTP`

*Update3:*
The KML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Testname</name>
    <Style id="ObstacleInfo">
        <LabelStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
        </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>40ffffff</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
    </Style>
            <Placemark>
            <name>Mast 363 ft AGL</name>
            <description>Wyhlen(Mast) 363 ft AGL/ 1.229 ft MSL</description>

            <styleUrl>#ObstacleInfo</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
                <extrude>1</extrude>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>
                                7.676111,47.536667,110
                                8.676111,47.536667,110
                                7.676111,47.636667,110
                                8.676111,47.636667,110
                                </coordinates>
            </LineString>
        </Placemark>        
</Document>
</kml>
```

*Update4:*
    `ogrinfo --version
    GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01`

```
ogrinfo --format KML
Format Details:
Short Name: KML
Long Name: Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
Supports: Vector
Extension: kml
Help Topic: drv_kml.html
Supports: Open() - Open existing dataset.
Supports: Create() - Create writable dataset.
Supports: Virtual IO - eg. /vsimem/
Creation Field Datatypes: Integer Real String


<CreationOptionList>
<Option name="GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS" type="boolean" description="Whether to write non-GPX attributes in an &lt;extensions&gt; tag" default="NO" />
<Option name="NameField" type="string" description="Field to use to fill the KML &lt;name&gt; element" default="Name" />
<Option name="DescriptionField" type="string" description="Field to use to fill the KML &lt;description&gt; element" default="Description" />
```

clampToGround
    relativeToGround
    absolute

Comment: KML is vector format and read by the OGR side of GDAL when used for example in gdal_rasterize. What does `ogrinfo test.kml` report?

Comment: @user30184 ogrinfo test.kml says: FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `nguyen_test.kml' with the following drivers.
I added the whole list into my question

Comment: And then `gdalinfo nguyen_test.kml`if is happens to be already a KML overlay?

Comment: @user30184 too bad thats not the case. gdalinfo tells me: `"ERROR 4: 'test.kml' not recognized as a supported file format.

gdalinfo failed - unable to open 'test.kml'`.

Comment: Without sample data I am lost, I apologize.

Comment: @user30184 I just added the kml content into the first question

Comment: That doesn't look like ogrinfo from GDAL 2.1.x - you probably have some older version loaded. `ogrinfo --version` and `ogrinfo --format KML` might be interesting to add. I can say it rendered for me with `gdal_rasterize -3d -ot Byte -a_srs EPSG:4326  -ts 1024 1024 foo.kml  out.tif` however my GDAL is built with LIBKML support.

Comment: I made a test with GDAL 2.2.0dev and ogrinfo reads your KML file both with LIBKML and KML drivers.

Comment: I rechecked the version and it is 2.1.3. can't find 2.2. on the official gdal homepage. 2.1.3 is the newest source. I will look into libkml.

Comment: 2.2 is a trunk version but I had no problem with OSGeo4W version either which is `GDAL 2.1.2, released 2016/10/24`

Answer (score 1):

Not reproduced:

```
$ gdal_rasterize -of "Gtiff" -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0 -burn 127 -init 0 -init 0 -init 0 -init 0 -ot Byte -ts 800 800 test.kml test.tiff
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
$ ogrinfo --version
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
$ ogrinfo --format KML
Format Details:
  Short Name: KML
  Long Name: Keyhole Markup Language (KML)
  Supports: Vector
  Extension: kml
  Help Topic: drv_kml.html
  Supports: Open() - Open existing dataset.
  Supports: Create() - Create writable dataset.
  Supports: Virtual IO - eg. /vsimem/
  Creation Field Datatypes: Integer Real String

  <CreationOptionList>
    <Option name="GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS" type="boolean" description="Whether to write non-GPX attributes in an &lt;extensions&gt; tag" default="NO" />
    <Option name="NameField" type="string" description="Field to use to fill the KML &lt;name&gt; element" default="Name" />
    <Option name="DescriptionField" type="string" description="Field to use to fill the KML &lt;description&gt; element" default="Description" />
    <Option name="AltitudeMode" type="string-select" description="Value of the &lt;AltitudeMode&gt; element for 3D geometries">
      <Value>clampToGround</Value>
      <Value>relativeToGround</Value>
      <Value>absolute</Value>
    </Option>
  </CreationOptionList>

  <LayerCreationOptionList />
```

[image]